# Tax and selling a property in the U.K. before moving to Canada

Tags: united-kingdom, canada, real-estate, capital-gains-tax, moving

I would appreciate some advise on this: If you sell a property in the UK to move to Canada, and then transfer the money from the sold property to Canada, will you have to pay tax in Canada on the money you transferred? Thank you for any help.

Comment: It depends. Would you be moving to live in Canada for the first time, or were you arleady considered a resident of Canada for income tax purposes, such as if you were a Canadian living in the U.K. temporarily and are now moving back to Canada?